# Grocery Crud where date greater than today

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I'm trying to display results in Grocery Crud where the posted date is greater than today, with no luck. Here is what I tried:

```
$crud->where('status','open');
$crud->or_where('posting_date','<'.$now);
```

The table returns results, but it just returns all results. `$now`  is set like so:

```
$dt = new DateTime();
$now = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: what is the format of data in posting_date column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you use Wrong less then condition in codeigniter it would be like this

```
 $crud->where('status','open');
 $crud->or_where('posting_date <',$now);
```

Comment: Is the below statement correct. I want to filter data by date range.

$code->where('time_in >=',$fromDate);
$code->where('time_in <= ',$toDate);